# I can't view the full image when trying to display camera output in full screen

Tags: java, android-studio, android-camera, android-fullscreen

I have had this issue for a few days already and I'm not sure how to fix it. I have a code to open the camera and display the output in full screen. but the displied image is not full. a part of it is not there. I added this function and it fixed the image but the display is not in full screen anymore.
here are the two images before and after adding the function

Before
[image]

After
[image]

the function I added

```
private void configureTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
        if (null == mTextureView || null == mPreviewSize) {
            return;
        }
        int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
        RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
        matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
        
        mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
    }
```

my Full code for the camera is here

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraMetadata;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureResult;
import android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.MeteringRectangle;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Size;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;
import static java.lang.Math.abs;
import static java.lang.Math.pow;


public class camera_ocr extends AppCompatActivity {



    static int CAMERA_FRONT_BACK = 0;

    private MeteringRectangle[] mAFRegions = AutoFocusHelperLib.getZeroWeightRegion();
    private MeteringRectangle[] mAERegions = AutoFocusHelperLib.getZeroWeightRegion();
    private Rect mCropRegion;
    private Boolean cameraReady = false;
    private static String versionName = "V7.7.5";
    private int flag = 0;
    private int[] position;
    private View linearLayout;
    private static final String TAG = "Camera Error";
    private int[] focusMode = {};
    private CameraCharacteristics cameraChar;
    private Fragment fragment;
    private Bitmap output;
    private static int totalRotation;
    ImageButton camera;
    ImageButton flashLight ;
    Button btnSnapPhoto;
    private static Boolean displayResult = false;
    Boolean cameraGranted = false;
    public static  String licenseKey ;
    ValueAnimator animation = null ;

    private int[] boxPosition = new int[4];
    private float [] cardPosation = new float[8];
    private static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION = 123;
    private String mCameraId;
    private Size mPreviewSize;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder mCaptureRequestBuilder;
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundHandlerThread;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private static SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    private float screenWidth ;
    private float screenHeight ;

    CameraCharacteristics characteristics;
    private CaptureRequest mPreviewRequest;
    private CameraCaptureSession mCaptureSession;

    private int mSensorOrientation;


    private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewRequestBuilder;
    private int mState = STATE_PREVIEW;

    private ImageReader mImageReader;



    private float cameraFocusDistance = 4.5f ;
    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 180);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 270);
    }
    private static CameraDevice mCameraDevice;

    /**
     * Camera state: Showing camera preview.
     */
    private static final int STATE_PREVIEW = 0;

    /**
     * Camera state: Waiting for the focus to be locked.
     */
    private static final int STATE_WAITING_LOCK = 1;

    /**
     * Camera state: Waiting for the exposure to be precapture state.
     */
    private static final int STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE = 2;

    /**
     * Camera state: Waiting for the exposure state to be something other than precapture.
     */
    private static final int STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE = 3;

    /**
     * Camera state: Picture was taken.
     */
    private static final int STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN = 4;

    /**
     * Max preview width that is guaranteed by Camera2 API
     */
    private static final int MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH = 1920;

    /**
     * Max preview height that is guaranteed by Camera2 API
     */
    private static final int MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT = 1080;
    private Semaphore mCameraOpenCloseLock = new Semaphore(1);
    CameraManager manager = null ;

    private AutoFitTextureViewLib mTextureView;

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void openCamera(int width, int height, int camera_front_back) {
        setUpCameraOutputs(width, height, camera_front_back);
        configureTransform(width, height);
        manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            if (!mCameraOpenCloseLock.tryAcquire(2500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Time out waiting to lock camera opening.");
            }

            manager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);

//            getCurrentPhoto();
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera opening.", e);
        }
    }

    static class CompareSizesByArea implements Comparator<Size> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
            // We cast here to ensure the multiplications won't overflow
            return Long.signum((long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() -
                    (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
        }
    }

    private static Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int textureViewWidth,
                                          int textureViewHeight, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, Size aspectRatio) {

        // Collect the supported resolutions that are at least as big as the preview Surface
        List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<>();
        // Collect the supported resolutions that are smaller than the preview Surface
        List<Size> notBigEnough = new ArrayList<>();
        int w = aspectRatio.getWidth();
        int h = aspectRatio.getHeight();
        for (Size option : choices) {
            if (option.getWidth() <= maxWidth && option.getHeight() <= maxHeight &&
                    option.getHeight() == option.getWidth() * h / w) {
                if (option.getWidth() >= textureViewWidth &&
                        option.getHeight() >= textureViewHeight) {
                    bigEnough.add(option);
                } else {
                    notBigEnough.add(option);
                }
            }
        }

        // Pick the smallest of those big enough. If there is no one big enough, pick the
        // largest of those not big enough.
        if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {
            return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
        } else if (notBigEnough.size() > 0) {
            return Collections.max(notBigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't find any suitable preview size");
            return choices[0];
        }
    }

    private void setUpCameraOutputs(int width, int height, int camera_front_back) {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            String cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[camera_front_back];
            characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);


            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(
                    CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            if (map == null) {
                return;
            }

            // For still image captures, we use the largest available size.
            Size largest = Collections.max(
                    Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)),
                    new CompareSizesByArea());
            mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(),
                    ImageFormat.JPEG, /*maxImages*/2);

            // Find out if we need to swap dimension to get the preview size relative to sensor
            // coordinate.
            int displayRotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            //noinspection ConstantConditions
            mSensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
            boolean swappedDimensions = false;
            switch (displayRotation) {
                case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                    if (mSensorOrientation == 90 || mSensorOrientation == 270) {
                        swappedDimensions = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                    if (mSensorOrientation == 0 || mSensorOrientation == 180) {
                        swappedDimensions = true;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.e(TAG, "Display rotation is invalid: " + displayRotation);
            }

            Point displaySize = new Point();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(displaySize);
            int rotatedPreviewWidth = width;
            int rotatedPreviewHeight = height;
            int maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.x;
            int maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.y;

            if (swappedDimensions) {
                rotatedPreviewWidth = height;
                rotatedPreviewHeight = width;
                maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.y;
                maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.x;
            }

            if (maxPreviewWidth > MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH) {
                maxPreviewWidth = MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH;
            }

            if (maxPreviewHeight > MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT) {
                maxPreviewHeight = MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT;
            }
            // Danger, W.R.! Attempting to use too large a preview size could  exceed the camera
            // bus' bandwidth limitation, resulting in gorgeous previews but the storage of
            // garbage capture data.
            mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                    rotatedPreviewWidth, rotatedPreviewHeight, maxPreviewWidth,
                    maxPreviewHeight, largest);

            // We fit the aspect ratio of TextureView to the size of preview we picked.
            int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                mTextureView.setAspectRatio(
                        mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            } else {
                mTextureView.setAspectRatio(
                        mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
            }


            mCropRegion = AutoFocusHelperLib.cropRegionForZoom(characteristics,
                    CameraConstantsLib.ZOOM_REGION_DEFAULT);

            mCameraId = cameraId;
            return;
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // Currently an NPE is thrown when the Camera2API is used but not supported on the
            // device this code runs.
        }
    }
    private void configureTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
        if (null == mTextureView || null == mPreviewSize) {
            return;
        }
        int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
        RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
        matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
        float centerX = viewRect.centerX();
        float centerY = viewRect.centerY();

        if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {
            bufferRect.offset(centerX - bufferRect.centerX(), centerY - bufferRect.centerY());
            matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
            float scale = Math.max(
                    (float) viewHeight / mPreviewSize.getHeight(),
                    (float) viewWidth / mPreviewSize.getWidth());
            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
            matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centerY);
        } else if (Surface.ROTATION_180 == rotation) {
            matrix.postRotate(180, centerX, centerY);
        }
        mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
    }

    private final CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            // This method is called when the camera is opened.  We start camera preview here.
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
            createCameraPreviewSession();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            cameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int error) {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            cameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
            finish();
        }

    };
    private void createCameraPreviewSession() {
        try {
            final int[] x = new int[1];
            final int[] y = new int[1];
            SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;

            // We configure the size of default buffer to be the size of camera preview we want.
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());

            // This is the output Surface we need to start preview.
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

            // We set up a CaptureRequest.Builder with the output Surface.
            mPreviewRequestBuilder
                    = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

            // Here, we create a CameraCaptureSession for camera preview.
            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, mImageReader.getSurface()),
                    new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                            // The camera is already closed
                            if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                                return;
                            }

                            // GET SCREEN SIZE
                            MeteringRectangle screenSize[] = mPreviewRequestBuilder.get(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_REGIONS);

                            // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                            mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;


                            long loopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

                            // GET SCREEN WIDTH
                            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
                            screenWidth = screenSize[0].getWidth();
                            screenHeight = screenSize[0].getHeight();

                            // CREATE NEW FOCUS POINT
                            // testing
                            for(int i = 0; i < 1 ; i++) {
                                setManualFocusAt(x[0], y[0]);

                                // GET CURRENT FOCUS POINT
                                MeteringRectangle currentFocusArea[] = mPreviewRequestBuilder.get(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_REGIONS);


                                time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                // WAIT FOR FOCUS TO READY
                                while((System.currentTimeMillis() - time) < 800){
                                    Log.d("focus time:" , Float.toString(System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
                                    Log.e("focus time:" , Float.toString(System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
                                    Log.wtf("focus time:" , Float.toString(System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
                                };
                            }
                            long x = System.currentTimeMillis() - loopTime;
                            Log.d("focus time:" , Float.toString(x));

                            cameraReady = true;

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConfigureFailed(
                                @NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        }
                    }, null
            );
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initiate a still image capture.
     */

    void setManualFocusAt(int x, int y) {
        int mDisplayOrientation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        float points[] = new float[2];
        points[0] = (float) x / mTextureView.getWidth();
        points[1] = (float) y / mTextureView.getHeight();
        Matrix rotationMatrix = new Matrix();
        rotationMatrix.setRotate(mDisplayOrientation, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        rotationMatrix.mapPoints(points);
        if (mPreviewRequestBuilder != null) {
//            mIsManualFocusing = true;
            updateManualFocus(points[0], points[1]);
            if (mCaptureSession != null) {
                try {
                    mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER,
                            CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);
                    mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
                    mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER,
                            CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_IDLE);
                    mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(),
                            null, mBackgroundHandler);
                } catch (CameraAccessException | IllegalStateException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to set manual focus.", e);
                }
            }
//            resumeAutoFocusAfterManualFocus();
        }
    }

    void updateManualFocus(float x, float y) {
        @SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
        int sensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
        mAFRegions = AutoFocusHelperLib.afRegionsForNormalizedCoord(x, y, mCropRegion, sensorOrientation);
        mAERegions = AutoFocusHelperLib.aeRegionsForNormalizedCoord(x, y, mCropRegion, sensorOrientation);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_REGIONS, mAFRegions);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_REGIONS, mAERegions);
//        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO);

        // fixe distance focuse // testing
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE, cameraFocusDistance);

    }

    /**
     * Lock the focus as the first step for a still image capture.
     */

    private void closeCamera() {
        try {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.acquire();
            if (null != mCaptureSession) {
                mCaptureSession.close();
                mCaptureSession = null;
            }
            if (null != mCameraDevice) {
                mCameraDevice.close();
                mCameraDevice = null;
            }
            if (null != mImageReader) {
                mImageReader.close();
                mImageReader = null;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera closing.", e);
        } finally {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        }
    }


    private final TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener
            = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture texture, int width, int height) {
            openCamera(width, height,CAMERA_FRONT_BACK);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture texture, int width, int height) {
            configureTransform(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture texture) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture texture) {
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_ocr);

        mTextureView = findViewById(R.id.textureView);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        if (mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
            openCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight(),CAMERA_FRONT_BACK);
        } else {
            mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you got height and width backwards on this line:

```
RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
```

Try the following and you should get the correct result:

```
RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
```

Comment: This did not work, it made the image stretched and also didn't fill the full screen

Comment: @abss If it didn't fill your screen then there is an issue with the sizes and scaling you have. Also, note that using `Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL` will always stretch the view to fix the given size (it's not possible to see the whole image and also avoid stretching unless the source and destination views are exactly the same scale). Add some debugging to print out the size of viewRect and bufferRect to see if they are what you expect, and also check that your rotation code is not breaking the scaling.

Comment: I have tried that multiple times, I tried to change the sizes so it is the same but non of that help. I could send u the full project(I have the camera part as a separate project to try) for you to try if u would like. I'm sure this is a lot to ask for, but I'm stuck in this for almost a week. Your help is much appreciated

Comment: @abss I suspect that `mPreviewSize` is not the actual size of the camera image. Add some debugging to see what size the actual camera image is, compare it to `mPreviewSize` and compare it to `viewRect`. I think you will discover a disconnect there somewhere.